# XMPP Smack 4.1.0 check is user is already registered

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

Hi Im using the Smack XMPP library for android.

I have figured out how to connect, login and create a user, but if I try to create an account with a username that already exist, i get a 'conflict' error, then if i change the username and try again, im locked out for about 10 mins, with a "not_acceptable - wait" error.

So how would i check if the username exists before creating an account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Roster](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.3/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/roster/Roster.html) as:

1. Create a side account.
2. Add all accounts to the roster of the account created previously.
3. Check if the username exists with :

   ```
   Collection<RosterEntry> re = roster.getEntries();
   ```

   And then search for the username in "re".

**EDIT :** Or simply you can use [userSearchManager](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/search/UserSearchManager.html)